# BackBone.js Child View not Rendering it's element when Parent View Adds Child's Targeted Element

Tags: backbone.js, rendering, parent-child, backbone-views

I've reviewed all the Backbone.js answers here on SO but could find none that resolved my issue; if I missed one that does please point me to it.

I'm trying to get a BackBone.js child view to render a static element contained in the HTML that it's parent view renders. I've created the simplest example I could to illustrate. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Child View Not Rendering</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the `test.js` Javascript:

```
(function () {
  var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#child',
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('World');
    }
  });
  var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#parent',
    initialize: function () {
      this.child = new Child();
    },
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('Hello <span id="child"></span>!');
      this.child.render();
    }
  });
  var parent = new Parent();
  parent.render();
})();
```

When this runs I only see `"Hello !"` instead of `"Hello World!"` in the browser. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

I found my own answer *(see my "Answer" below)* but now I'm still wondering if my solution is the best approach or if I should not still be creating `new Child()` in `Parent.initialize()` and figuring out how to make `Child.$el` act as if it were using `jQuery.live()`.  Ideas?

### UPDATE #2

I found another answer that leaves the creation of `new Child()` in `Parent.initialize()`  *(see the UPDATE in my "Answer" below)*. It requires using jQuery to assign the `.$el` property and from that it reassigns the `.el` property in `Child.render()` but it feels like a hack. I ask again, is there not a better way?

### UPDATE #3

I was able to find a cleaner way to assign the `.$el` property; `.setElement()`; see my **UPDATE #2** in my answer below. And still looking for a better way.

### UPDATE #4

Found a way to create a "parent" class that encapsulates the ugliness although it's not [composable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composability) with other `.constructor()` chaining; see my **UPDATE #3** in my answer below.  I'd still like to find a [mixin strategy](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) that requires minimal code to extend a View. **So that's what I'll leave this question to be open for**; anyone with a great answer? Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE #5

Scratch **UPDATE #4** here; it causes a slew of problems. **So, if anyone can work through the issues and also make this as a workable mixin that doesn't require a lot of code to mixin I'll happily given them the selected answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the child's element is just being rendered in memory and never added to the DOM. You have `#child` as the element for the Child view, but this isn't in the HTML. So you could change your HTML to:

```
<div id="parent"></div>
<div id="child"></div>
```

Which will put "World" into the DOM, inside #child..

However, I'm assuming because these are named parent and child, you actually want them nested in which case the parent would be in charge of rendering the child. If so, change your child view to:

```
var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'child',
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html('World');
        return this;
    }
});
```

This removes the 'el' selector and adds and 'id' property instead, because this is being dynamically created. Secondly, the render method returns this because: "A good convention is to return this at the end of render to enable chained calls." - Backbone docs.

Then in your parent view you can call:

```
this.$el.append(this.child.render().el);
```

Which renders the child element into into memory and then adds it into the DOM inside the parent div.

Comment: Thanks Ian! Your explanation really helped, however I don't think either solutions fit my exact use-case. The first solution _(as you surmised)_ won't work because I want to do it dynamically. And the second solution which I'm sure I'll use in the future doesn't address the ability for me to target a known ID that is in my parent's template _(I didn't explain the use of a template in my question; it's key to my current needs but wasn't needed in my example.)_ If I `.append()` the child I'm effectively building the HTML in JS instead of what I want which is to have the HTML be in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I have found my own solution. It seems that the value of `'#child'` for `Child.el` is thrown away on `new Child()` because the ID did not exist in the DOM at the time. So by moving `this.child = new Child();` from `Parent.initialize()` to `Parent.render()` I was able to make it work.

Here's the working Javascript that does display `"Hello World!"` in the browser:

```
(function () {
  var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#child',
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('World');
    }
  });
  var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#parent',
    initialize: function () {
    },
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('Hello <span id="child"></span>!');
      this.child = new Child();
      this.child.render();
    }
  });
  var parent = new Parent();
  parent.render();
})();
```

### UPDATE

I found another solution but it feels like a real hack. This time I moved the creation of `new Child()` back into `Parent.initialize()` and in `Child.initialize()`. And I added the following code in advance of the actual rendering which assigns the `.$el` property and from it reassigns the `.el` property:

```
this.$el = $("#child");
this.el = this.$el[0];
```

I also added the `return this;` to each `.render()` that [@Ian Routledge](/users/486434/ian-routledge) reminded me I should be using.

Here's the full updated Javascript code:

```
(function () {
  var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
      this.$el = $("#child");
      this.el = this.$el[0];
      this.$el.html('World');
      return this;
    }
  });
  var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#parent',
    initialize: function () {
      this.child = new Child();
    },
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('Hello <span id="child"></span>!');
      this.child.render();
      return this;
    }
  });
  var parent = new Parent();
  parent.render();
})();
```

Not sure which solution I'll be using, but it's nice to know how to make them both work.

### UPDATE #2

Well, my lack of experience with Backbone.js is showing. There's a cleaner way to do the above. Instead of:

```
this.$el = $("#child");
this.el = this.$el[0];
```

We can use this:

```
this.setElement('#child', false);
```

And the full updated Javascript code is here:

```
(function () {
  var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
      this.setElement('#child', false);
      this.$el.html('World');
      return this;
    }
  });
  var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#parent',
    initialize: function () {
      this.child = new Child();
    },
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('Hello <span id="child"></span>!');
      this.child.render();
      return this;
    }
  });
  var parent = new Parent();
  parent.render();
})();
```

### UPDATE #3

One *(hopefully)* final update: I was able to isolate the hacky code and move into a *"parent"* class I called `DynamicChildView`. I added my own `.constructor()` which saves `this.el` and `this.render`, sets `.render()` to a function that resets `.el/.$el` and then call the child's `.render()`, and then finally calls the implicit constructor in `Backbone.View`.

Here's the newest Javascript code:

```
(function () {

  var DynamicChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
    constructor: function(attributes,options) {
      this._childEl = this.el;
      this._childRender = this.render;
      this.render = function () {
        this.el = this.el || this._childEl;
        this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'), false);
        this._childRender();
        return this;
      };
      Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this,attributes,options);
    }
  });

  var Child = DynamicChildView.extend({
    el: "#child",
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('World');
      return this;
    }
  });

  var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#parent',
    initialize: function () {
      this.child = new Child();
    },
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('Hello <span id="child"></span>!');
      this.child.render();
      return this;
    }
  });
  var parent = new Parent();
  parent.render();
})();
```

This approach is probably better but not composable with other extensions that override the constructor. I'd like to figure out how to make it a mixin that doesn't require a lot of code to include with new views but that's probably all the time I've got to devote to it today.

### UPDATE #4

Scratch the solution in **UPDATE #3** in my answer immediate above; it causes all kind of problems. Back to this answer's **UPDATE #2**.

Comment: Mike, I am a Backbone newb too, and this question is a bit old so you probably don't care anymore, but maybe for someone else - it might be best for the child to create its own el and then simply call $('#el-inside-parent').html() in the child render function. Hope that makes sense.